# How to declare variables with unique name in python?

Tags: python-3.x, z3, solver

A program receives a map `vars`, which maps the name and type of variables in `pathCons`. Now, I want to solve this `path_cons`, I designed the following `parse()` function to try to implement it.
However, to make `solver` identify all variables in `path_cons`, I have to first declare them. But their names are recorded into a variable, so how do I implement my goal?

```
def parse(vars, pathCons):
    for var in list(vars.keys()):
       if vars[var] == "uint":
           ???(should be name of var) = BitVec(var, 256)
       elif vars[x] == "bool":
           ??? = Bool(var)
   solver.add(eval(path_cons))
```

I thought of an idea that I randomly generate a unique name for each variable and then replace them with the new names in `path_cons`. But similarly, the generated name is also a value that cannot be as a name of variables.

For example,

```
vars = {"length":"int", "balance":"uint", "day":"uint", "flag":"bool"}
pathcons = "length>9, ULT(day, 10), UGE(balance + day, 100), flag == true"
```

Now I receive these two variables, and I want to solve `pathcons`.

Comment: The canonical equivalent to "variable variables" are ``dict`` or ``list`` for named or enumerated variables. Likewise, ``eval`` can directly use a ``dict`` for both globals/locals. Is there any reason why you try to ``eval`` in the actual local namespace?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  As far as I know, the ```dict``` in eval is to give an initial value of for variables in ```eval``` str. But the z3 solver still needs variables declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here. Stack-overflow works the best if you post code that people can run and see the issue you're running into.

But it seems to me that you want to create a bunch of z3 names corresponding to some notion of variables you have. To do so, simply create an array of them and use it accordingly. I'd do:

```py
from z3 import *

progVars = {"length":"int", "balance":"uint", "day":"uint", "flag":"bool"}

def mkVar(var):
    if progVars[var] == "uint":
        return BitVec(var, 256)
    elif progVars[var] == "bool":
        return Bool(var)
    elif progVars[var] == "int":
        return Int(var)
    else:
        raise Exception("Don't know how to handle %s" % progVars[var])

z3Vars = [{"progVar": v, "z3Var": mkVar(v)} for v in progVars.keys()]

print(z3Vars)
```

This prints:

```
[{'progVar': 'length', 'z3Var': length}, {'progVar': 'balance', 'z3Var': balance}, {'progVar': 'flag', 'z3Var': flag}, {'progVar': 'day', 'z3Var': day}]
```

Notice how our dictionary is now indexed by your "program keys", and for each we store the created z3 variable in the `z3Var` field. Those will be true symbolic values that you can later manipulate with z3, add to the solver with constraints etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It inspirs me and works on my problems perfectly!!!

Comment: One more question: Assuming a set of constrints :`x>y && (y>x || y==10 && y>z)` , how can I express them through z3 grammar in python, i.e. using `,` `Or`. I think `(x>y, Or(y>x,( y== 10, y>z)) ` cannot express their original meaning.

Comment: It's best to ask separate questions; stack-overflow comments are designed for simple exchanges over the particular question being designed. Having said that, use `Or` for disjunction, `And` for conjunction, and `Implies` for implication, and `If` for general conditionals when programming in z3py.